# Extend "Python Template String" to Non-ASCII

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, templates

I'm trying to fill values in a formula string by using [Python Template Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings). The formula sometimes contains identifiers having non-ASCII characters like α, ß, Γ etc. *(see [Unicode Greek and Coptic Chart](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0370.pdf))*. But as per python documentation, the template string is limited to only ASCII identifiers.
The default regular expression to match the identifier is `(?a:[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*)`.

How can I extend the default regular expression so it also matches the characters from [Unicode Greek and Coptic Chart](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0370.pdf)?

Comment: Theoretically, you should be able to change `Template.idpattern` to accept non-ASCII identifiers. Practically, that does not seem to work.

Comment: I checked it too. Probably because the pattern is compiled already during the instantiating process. I used the following method to solve my problem.

`
`from string import Template as _Template`

`class Template(_Template):`
   `idpattern = r'([_a-z\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF\u0370-\u03FF][_a-z\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF\u0370-\u03FF0-9]*)'`

Comment: But `\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF` are not in the list you refer to in the question. Do you mean to match any Unicode letters?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The question is not about how to write a regex for identifiers, but how to make `Template` recognize it.

Comment: @DYZ Sir for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I was able to solve my problem.

```
from string import Template as _Template

    class Template(_Template):
        """Created a custom template class becasue default Template class doesn't support non ASCII identifiers"""
        idpattern = r'([_a-z\u0370-\u03FF][_a-z0-9\u0370-\u03FF]*)'
```

The subclass is required because python compiles a regex pattern during class initialization and the default `Template.idpattern` is fixed and have no effect if changed at a later stage.